# Can a program behave differently on different compilers?

Tags: c, arrays

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main(){
    char a[] = {80, 65, 84, 84, 69, 82, 78};
    int i;
    for( i = 0; a[i]; ++i){
        printf("%c", a[i]);
    }
    //printf("%s", a); 
    return 0;
}
```

I think this program should throw a runtime error, yes it did when i ran through leetcode online IDE, but it printed PATTERN when i ran through Codechef IDE.

Please explain me ,what is happening here?
Thank You

Comment: Yes, code can result in different functionality on different compilers by invoking implementation-defined behavior or undefined behavior.  In this case, reading past the end of the array results in undefined behavior.

Comment: You have undefined behavior. You're _not_ guaranteeing that a 0 value is at the end of the array. After 78, the next value is random [instead of 0] and it's whatever just happens to be there. Your loop could continue indefinitely, until, just by luck, it finds a 0 somewhere. To fix, do this: `char a[] = {80, 65, 84, 84, 69, 82, 78, 0};` (note the extra 0 at the end).

Answer (score 6):

> I think this program should throw a runtime error

No such thing is defined by the C language.

```
for( i = 0; a[i]; ++i){
```

This loop terminates on the first zero-valued element of the `a` array. However there is no such element. As such, you're overrunning the `a` array, resulting in Undefined Behavior.

```
printf("%s", a);
```

Same here. The `%s` specifier expects a NUL-terminated character array (i.e. "C-string"), but the array you've given it is not NUL-terminated. This results in Undefined Behavior.

Anything can happen when you invoke Undefined Behavior, including differing behavior between compilers, machines, the phase of the moon, etc.

You have two options for fixing this broken program:

1. Terminate your `a` array with a `0` element at the end.

```
    char a[] = {80, 65, 84, 84, 69, 82, 78, 0};
```

2. Change your program to not expect NUL-terminated arrays, and use a length limit instead.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main(){
    char a[] = {80, 65, 84, 84, 69, 82, 78};
    int alen = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < alen; ++i){
        printf("%c", a[i]);
    }
    printf("%.*s", alen, a); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can a program behave differently on different compilers?

Yes, there are very many parts of C's semantics that the C standard leaves implementation defined, unspecified or even undefined. All of these allow different compilers (or even the same compiler) to behave differently.

> I think this program should throw a runtime error

The C language does not have a concept of runtime errors. Most things that you think should produce a runtime error, will have undefined behavior instead. That means it *may* crash on any given compiler or it may also do anything else.

All common compilers implement array accesses without any bound checks (at least by default), which means that the program will simply access memory outside of the array when you leave the bounds of the array. This may cause a crash if you happen to also run outside of the bounds of your process's memory (or indirectly if the overwritten memory causes other things to go wrong as well, such as overwriting a return address and then returning into non-sense) or it may just overwrite memory that belongs to your process and cause all kinds of weird behavior.

As far as the language is concerned, it may also make demons fly out of your nose, but that's not a behavior commonly exhibited by real implementations.